# Jenkins build flow plugin not showing graph of dependencies

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to show the dependencies graph built by Jenkins Build Flow plugin?

I'm referring the the graph made by the Dependency Graph View plugin.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Graph+View+Plugin

The answer is to install this plugin which does work with the Build Flow plugin.